# SQL Server: selecting a row multiple times by the given factor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select from a table but the problem is, I have a factor column that indicates how many times this row must be selected (this a sample table just for demonstration):

```
ID        Factor         Count
-------------------------------
1            1             235        
2            2             345        
3            2             214        
4            3             95        
5            1             135        
6            1             750
```

Query:

```
select top 6 
   [id], [count] 
from 
   table
order by 
    id                  --somewhere in here I must take factor into consideration
```

The result must be:

```
ID            Count
---------------------
 1            235                    
 2            345                    
 2            345                    
 3            214                    
 3            214                    
 4            135
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL is my first thought.

Comment: @TabAlleman you mean writing a dynamic query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM dbo.YourTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT *
            FROM master.dbo.spt_values
            WHERE type = 'P') B
    ON A.Factor >= B.number+1
```

[**Here is a sqfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0870d/1) with a demo of it.

And the results are:

```
╔════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ Factor ║ Count ║
╠════╬════════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║      1 ║   235 ║
║  2 ║      2 ║   345 ║
║  2 ║      2 ║   345 ║
║  3 ║      2 ║   214 ║
║  3 ║      2 ║   214 ║
║  4 ║      3 ║    95 ║
║  4 ║      3 ║    95 ║
║  4 ║      3 ║    95 ║
║  5 ║      1 ║   135 ║
║  6 ║      1 ║   750 ║
╚════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

If the `factor` column can be greater than 2048, then you can use a numbers table.

Comment: hey, that's nifty.  I didn't know about that table!  So much has become simpler.

Comment: no the factor is max 4, can you explain what this spt_values and its type and number column is?

Comment: @Greenspark Well, yeah, it's highly recommended that you have your own numbers table though (with more values)

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I'm just using that table in the case that you don't have a numbers table (which I recommend you do). The `master.dbo.spt_values` is a system table, the `number` column is an `INT`, when using `type = 'P'` this table gives you 2048 rows, from 0 to 2047

Comment: ohhhh, now I get it, Thanks a lot

Comment: what if master database is not accessible in production environment

Comment: @Pradeep As I said, then use a numbers table. Or create one on execution time as the answer below. There's no problem in creating a table with 6 rows

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the 'max' factor is.

```
SELECT [id],[count] 
FROM table
WHERE factor > 1

UNION ALL

SELECT [id],[count] 
FROM table
WHERE factor > 2

UNION ALL

SELECT [id],[count] 
FROM table
WHERE factor > 3

.
.
.

order by [id]
```

There's probably a way to do this with a recursive CTE.  Don't know how much effort you want to put into it.

Comment: I need to show 6 banners a page and some people choose to show their banners just one per page, some others allow more than one banner per page

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate for using a "tally" a.k.a. "numbers" table, which it just a table that contains a list of incremental integers.

Here is an example using a common table expression (CTE) to create a "tally" table on the fly.

```
WITH lv0 AS (SELECT 0 g UNION ALL SELECT 0)
    ,lv1 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv0 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b) -- 4
    ,lv2 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv1 a CROSS JOIN lv1 b) -- 16
    ,lv3 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv2 a CROSS JOIN lv2 b) -- 256
    ,lv4 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv3 a CROSS JOIN lv3 b) -- 65,536
    ,lv5 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv4 a CROSS JOIN lv4 b) -- 4,294,967,296
    ,Tally (n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM lv5)
SELECT TOP 6 t.[id], t.[count]
FROM table t
INNER JOIN Tally n on n.n <= t.factor
ORDER BY t.[id]
```

Or, if the "factor" could be a large number or you run into performance issues using the query above, then you would probably want to create a physical table for your tally table instead of using a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way of doing it with CTE.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT id,Factor,count
         FROM   tablename
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id,Factor - 1,count
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  Factor > 1)
SELECT a.ID,b.Factor,a.Count
FROM   cte a
       JOIN #tablename b
         ON a.Count = b.Count
ORDER  BY id
```

OUTPUT

```
ID  Factor  Count
--  ------  -----
1   1       235
2   2       345
2   2       345
3   2       214
3   2       214
4   3       95
4   3       95
4   3       95
5   1       135
6   1       750
```